# iphone UITextView exception

Tags: iphone

The following code goes to exception for 3.1.3:

> [textView select:self]

unrecognized selector sent to instance etc..

But the same code is working for 3.2.

I don't understand the error since this function is available starting from IPHONE_3_0 !!!

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Using a private API, I can perform cut/copy/paste for 3.1.3

For example: select

[[textView webView] select:self];

It seems that the UIWebView child of text view is the first responder for these edit actions.

By the way, on iPad(3.2), the UITextView implements the informal protocol UIResponderStandardEditActions directly!